# Iphone-Display Records from and NsMutable Array

Tags: iphone

Suppose i have a `NSMutableArray` with 20 objects.

On my `viewDidLoad` i want to show first 10 records, and click on a `UIButton` say NextButton i want to show the remaining records.

And when i click back it should go back to 10 records which was first shown on `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: First read http://stackoverflow.com/faq then tell what you have tried and then share some code...

Comment: that sounds cool - what error are you getting?

Comment: Read about `UITableView` that's one of the standard way of showing `NSMutableArray` and **after** trying some things out ask a question, and people will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You should divide yourMainArray as two arrays. After that you fill up elements into arrays and implement code as you want.

```
    NSMutableArray *arrayFirst10 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arraySecond10 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
      [arrayFirst10 addObject:[yourMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }

    for(int i=10;i<20;i++)
    {
      [arraySecond10 addObject:[yourMainArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

Try like this. It will be helpful to you.